# How to show the contents of log file in browser screen using Spring Actuator?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-logback

I'm trying to show the contents of a logger file in the browser screen , so that when the application is running in production in external server, i don't need to login every time into the server to fetch the logs. I'm trying to achieve this using Spring Boot Actuator. I have configured the log file path and log info level in my properties file, and logs are being written in that file, but how to stream the contents of the file in browser window. below is my properties file contents

```
  management.security.enabled=false
  endpoints.env.enabled=false
  endpoints.configprops.enabled=false
  endpoints.autoconfig.enabled=false
  endpoints.beans.enabled=false
  endpoints.dump.enabled=true
  endpoints.heapdump.enabled=true
  logging.level.root=info
  logging.file=target/app.log
```

Thanks for the help in advance !!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring Boot Admin: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin

The logs appear like this:

[image]

You can use https://start.spring.io/ to include de Admin Client and Server in your project. Check the tutorial here: http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#getting-started

Answer (score 1):

By default, the following Spring Boot Actuator endpoints are enabled (JMX/WEB):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints

To enable specific endpoints write the following in Spring Boot `application.properties` file:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include = info, health, logfile
```

or to disable write:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude = env,beans
```

Answer (score 0):

**Logs in the browser:**

One way to expose the logs from a Spring Boot application in the browser is by using the built-in Actuator endpoints.

Actuator is a tool that provides production-ready features to help you monitor and manage your Spring Boot application. It includes a variety of endpoints, including one for viewing the application logs.

To enable the Actuator endpoints, you need to add the spring-boot-starter-actuator dependency to your project's pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Once the dependency is added, you can access the log endpoint at `http://localhost:8080/actuator/logfile`.

To expose the logs in the browser, you can create a custom endpoint that reads the log file and returns its contents. Here's an example:

```
@RestController
public class LogController {

    @GetMapping("/logs")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getLogs() throws IOException {
        Path logFile = Paths.get(System.getProperty("logging.file.name"));
        String logs = new String(Files.readAllBytes(logFile));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(logs);
    }
}
```

Make sure the application is configured to write logs into a file, by adding the following to the `application.properties` or `application.yml` file:

```
logging.file.name=mylog.log
logging.level.root=INFO
```

This code creates a new endpoint at `http://localhost:8080/logs` that returns the contents of the log file as a string.

Note that **this approach may not be suitable for production environments** as it exposes potentially sensitive information. It is recommended to restrict access to the log endpoint using appropriate security measures.